# Custom footer on first page (using `hook')

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, footer

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of new paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % no footer line
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \thelastpage}

\fancypagestyle{default}{
\rfoot[]{\textbf{(TURN OVER})}
}

\fancypagestyle{last-page}{
    \rfoot[]{\textbf{END OF PAPER}}
}

\pagestyle{default}% Default page style
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{last-page}} % Last page style



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\lipsum[3]
\newpage

\lipsum[4]
\newpage

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

The code in `\fancypagestyle{default}` and `\fancypagestyle{last-page}` handle the custom footers for regular pages and the last page respectively.

I was wondering if the method I've used could be used to define a custom footer for the **first page**? That is, with a hook like `AtEndDocument`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You can use \AtBeginDocument:

\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % space at start of new paragraph
\setlength{\parskip}{0.14in} % space between paragraphs
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % no footer line
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \thelastpage}

\fancypagestyle{default}{
\rfoot[]{\textbf{(TURN OVER})}
}

\fancypagestyle{first-page}{
\rfoot[]{\textbf{(FIRST PAGE})}
}

\fancypagestyle{last-page}{
    \rfoot[]{\textbf{END OF PAPER}}
}

\pagestyle{default}% Default page style
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{last-page}} % Last page style

\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{first-page}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\lipsum[2]
\newpage

\lipsum[3]
\newpage

\lipsum[4]
\newpage

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```